# td valign="top" not working - CSS overriding somewhere

Tags: css, html-table, vertical-alignment, valign

**ANSWERED!**

I have some css overriding my tables but I don't know how to find it. I simply need images in my table to be at the top of the table. I use the code:

```
<td valign="top"><img src="../../../images/site/orangeBanner.png" alt="" width="259" height="62" class="imagePic"/></td>
```

But it does not work and produces this image of the orange bar in the middle. It should be at the top at the same height as "INSPIRE".

[image]

Here is the link to my full code: [FULL CODE](http://new.statuesplus.com/page/about)

**Can anyone see why my valign="top" is not working?** Is there anything to override the css?

Comment: valign isn't compatible with HTML5 (if you're using), use CSS vertical-align: top;

Comment: screen.css has this rule which is overriding it `table, th, td { vertical-align: middle; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `td` originally has `vertical-align: middle` specified inside the CSS. You can override it by using `style="vertical-align: top;"` inline inside the `<td>` tag containing your image. This should work perfectly:

```
<td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;"><img src="../../../images/site/orangeBanner.png" alt="" width="259" height="62" class="imagePic"/></td>
```

Comment: BAM! That did it. Thanks Fahad! :)

Comment: P.S. What css has the vertical-align: middle? I can't find it. What is the css link?

Comment: @papadebeau These three elements `table, th, td` have the style `vertical-align: middle;` specified at `line 21` inside the `screen.css` stylesheet.

Comment: @papadebeau Please mark my answer as the correct one so that users can know that your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I will. I tried but it said I had to wait 12 minutes. Not sure why Stack does that but be assured I will answer asap. :) Thank you! This is why I put ANSWERED at the top until I can mark it correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

This CSS rule is overriding it:

```
table, th, td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Change it to top or add another class to that specific td tag.
Also you could add style tag to that td as follows:

```
style="vertical-align: top;"
```